# Cannot initialize input with ng-minlength

Tags: angularjs

When I use  ng-minlength, and set input field to "x"
, the input field doesn't show "x"

```
<body ng-app="docu" ng-controller="formCtrl">  
        <input type="text" ng-minlength="4"  ng-model="deal.cupon">
</body>

var docu = angular.module('docu', []);

docu.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.deal = {};
    $scope.deal.cupon = "x";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jivangilad/8wmEP/

Comment: "x" is shorter than 4 characters.

Comment: @Mosho even if x is shorter than 4 characters, I think the user should be able to see the content of an invalid pre-filled input.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used the ng-minlength directive on the input, it will not show your ng-model value until it meets the minimum length criteria that you have specified.

Based on your comment below, I recommend that you take a look at the ng-form directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form).  You can use this to encapsulate one to many inputs, selects, etc. and run validation on the fly.  This will prevent form submission based on the rules you setup for each control within the form.

Comment: I do want to allow the input to have with 1 char length, I just don't want it to be valid, so the user cannot post the form